# Как правильно организовать код, чтобы убрать лишнее?

Tags: javascript

Есть 2 функции

```
$scope.dateDifference = function(dateBegin, dateFinish) {
  var dateDifference = ((Math.floor((dateFinish) / 1000)) - (Math.floor((dateBegin) / 1000)));
  var seconds = dateDifference % 60;
  dateDifference -= seconds;
  dateDifference = Math.floor(dateDifference / 60);
  var minutes = dateDifference % 60;
  dateDifference -= minutes;
  dateDifference = Math.floor(dateDifference / 60);
  var hours = dateDifference % 60;
  if (hours < 10) hours = '0' + hours;
  if (minutes < 10) minutes = '0' + minutes;
  if (seconds < 10) seconds = '0' + seconds;
  dateDifference = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
  return dateDifference;
}  

$scope.startTIME = function() {
  var thisDate = new Date();
  var t = ((Math.floor(thisDate / 1000)) - (Math.floor($scope.currentTask.dateBegin / 1000)));
  var s = t % 60;
  t -= s;
  t = Math.floor(t / 60);
  var m = t % 60;
  t -= m;
  t = Math.floor(t / 60);
  var h = t % 60;
  if (h < 10) h = '0' + h;
  if (m < 10) m = '0' + m;
  if (s < 10) s = '0' + s;
  if (isStart == 0) $scope.clock = h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
  clocktimer = $timeout($scope.startTIME, 1000);
}
```

Выполняющие по сути одни задачи, как можно сократить код?

```
 $scope.quickStart=function(tasks){
      if (isStart) {
        $scope.style = {
          background: 'red'
        };
        $scope.start();
        $scope.startTIME();
        $scope.tasks.name;
        isStart = false;
        $scope.buttonText = "Stop";
        $scope.currentTask.name=tasks.name;
        $scope.currentTask.selectedProject=tasks.selectedProject;

      } else {
        $scope.style = {
          background: 'red'
        };
        $scope.stop();
        var restart = $timeout($scope.quickStart, 100);
        $scope.currentTask.name=tasks.name;
        $scope.currentTask.selectedProject=tasks.selectedProject;
        isStart = true;
        $scope.buttonText = "Stop";
      }
    }
```

и

```
var isStart = true;
    $scope.buttonText = "Start";

    $scope.startOrStop = function() {
      if (isStart) {
        $scope.style = {
          background: 'red'
        };
        $scope.start();
        $scope.startTIME();
        isStart = false;
        $scope.buttonText = "Stop";
      } else {
        $scope.style = {
          background: '#11dc51'
        };
        $scope.stop();
        isStart = true;
        $scope.buttonText = "Start";
      }
    };
```

Comment: Как минимум `$scope.startTIME = function() { if (isStart == 0) $scope.clock = $scope.dateDifference($scope.currentTask.dateBegin, new Date()); clocktimer = $timeout($scope.startTIME, 1000); }`  А вообще что то мне подсказывает что в JS должны быть функции форматирующие дату подходящим образом в текстовом виде.

Comment: @Mike , можете помочь ещё с двумя функциями? добавил в описание

Comment: В первой функции вынесите одинаковые действия перед if, их там много. причем можно написать `isStart=!isStart` опять же вне if.

Comment: @Mike а как это будет выглядеть?

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример функции как можно сделать.

Так же для работы с датами есть неплохая библиотека [moment](https://github.com/moment/moment). Позволяет удобно форматировать, изменять и сравнивать даты. Собственно, в ней есть возможность форматировать дату шаблонами, чего нативно в JavaScript'е нет.

```js
var diffTime = function( otherTime ) {
  var date = new Date( Date.now() - otherTime )
  
  var time = [
      date.getHours(),
      date.getMinutes(),
      date.getSeconds()
  ]
    .map( function( n ) {
      // Редактирует число в двухзнаковое
      return ( '0' + n ).substr( -2 )
    } )
    .join( ':' )

  return time
}

var otherTime = Date.now() - 30000;
alert( diffTime( otherTime ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Как то так

```js
 $scope.startOrStop = startOrStop;
 $scope.quickStart = quickStart;
 $scope.style = {};

function startOrStop() {
    if (!isStart) {
      $scope.style.background = '#11dc51';
      return stop("Start");
    }
    start();
  };

function quickStart(tasks){
    $scope.currentTask.name=tasks.name;
    $scope.currentTask.selectedProject=tasks.selectedProject;
    if (!isStart) {
      $scope.style.background = 'red';
      var restart = $timeout($scope.quickStart, 100);
     return stop("Stop");
    }
    start();
};

function start(){
    $scope.style.background = 'red';
    $scope.start();
    $scope.startTIME();
    isStart = false;
    $scope.buttonText = "Stop";
};

function stop(buttonText){
  $scope.stop();
  isStart = true;
  $scope.buttonText = buttonText;
};
```